# How to pass a selection from one database to another via dblink?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'm using `PostgreSQL 8.4`. I have two databases, call them `db1` and `db2`. In the `db1` database I have the table `tbl1` which contains the following columns (all dates have `timestamp without timezone` format):

```
    date_from               date_to
-------------------    -------------------
2014-05-27 00:00:00    2014-05-27 23:59:59
2014-10-30 00:00:00    2014-10-30 23:59:59
2013-10-19 00:00:00    2013-10-19 23:59:59
2013-07-10 00:00:00    2013-07-10 23:59:59
2013-06-24 00:00:00    2013-06-24 23:59:59
2012-07-14 00:00:00    2012-07-14 23:59:59
2012-05-13 00:00:00    2012-05-13 23:59:59
2013-01-04 00:00:00    2013-01-04 23:59:59
2013-03-26 00:00:00    2013-03-26 23:59:59
...................    ...................
```

In the `db2` database I have the `player` table which contains `registration_date` and `id` as `PK` columns as follows:

```
 id      registration_date
----    -------------------
 1      2012-06-27 12:03:20
 2      2012-05-13 04:46:18
 3      2013-01-04 21:31:10
 4      2013-03-26 10:17:02
...     ...................
```

I need to get the selection which contains the following

```
    date_from               date_to              player_count
-------------------    -------------------    ------------------- 
2014-05-27 00:00:00    2014-05-27 23:59:59           ...
2014-10-30 00:00:00    2014-10-30 23:59:59
2013-10-19 00:00:00    2013-10-19 23:59:59
2013-07-10 00:00:00    2013-07-10 23:59:59
2013-06-24 00:00:00    2013-06-24 23:59:59
2012-07-14 00:00:00    2012-07-14 23:59:59
2012-05-13 00:00:00    2012-05-13 23:59:59
2013-01-04 00:00:00    2013-01-04 23:59:59
2013-03-26 00:00:00    2013-03-26 23:59:59
...................    ...................
```

where `player_count` is the is the number of players registered in the interval from `date_from` to `date_to`, where both `date_from` and `date_to` are from `db1.tbl1`.

Of course, I can use `dblink` query to get data from `db2` when I'm being connected to `db1`, but how to pass the query-result into a `dblink`-query?
`SELECT * FROM dblink(conn_str, query) AS ...;` where `query` is just a string and it doesn't know about any query results.

Comment: can you show query. what you have tried

Comment: @POHH No, because I have no idea how to write the query.

Comment: this might help you understand or will redirect you to right way
http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/dblink.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you really need both tables `join` them:

```
select date_from, date_to, count(*)
from
    dblink(conn_str, $$
        select registration_date
        from player
    $$) p (registration_date)
    inner join
    t on p.registration_date between t.date_from and t.date_to
group by date_from, date_to
```

But in your example the `player` table is enough:

```
select date_trunc('day', registration_date), count(*)
from player
group by 1
order by 1
```